# what does << and >> mean in swift

Tags: ios, macos, swift, swift2

I created a variable like this:

```
let value:Int8 = 55
```

and I find that I can do something like

```
value >> 3 // and the result is 6


value << 3 // and the result is 72-
```

I would like to ask you:

1. What does these >> and << mean in swift?
2. How these numbers in my code are being calculated?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`<<` Logical left shift

`>>` Logical right shift

[For more information](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AdvancedOperators.html)

Your Int8 55 is represented in binary as:

> 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1

`value >> 3` means to shift the bits to the right and add zeros in the empty bits, so you end up with

> 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0

which is 6 in decimal

`value << 3` means to shift the bits to the left and add zeros to the empty bits, so you end up with:

> 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0

and it is -72 in decimal

Notice that this is a negative number because the most significant bit (the most bit to the left) is one.
And iOS and OSX use [2’s complement](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations#2.27s_complement) to store negative numbers.